# Simulating a Drag/Drop event in WPF

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I want to simulate a drag/drop event in WPF.
For this I'll need to gain access to the data stored in the "Drag/Drop buffer" and also I'll need to create a `DragEventArgs`.
I noticed that the `DragEventArgs` is sealed and has no public ctor.

So my questions are:
1. how can I create an instance of `DragEventArgs`?
2. How can I gain access to the drag/drop buffer?

Answer (score 0):

i recently do this! i simulated drag/drop with MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp events. for example for my application, i have some canvases that i want to drag and drop them. every canvas has an id. in MouseDown event, i buffer its id and use it in MouseMove and MouseUp event. Desktop_Canvas is my main Canvas that contains some canvases. these canvases are in my dictionary (dic).

here is my code:

```
private Dictionary<int, Win> dic = new Dictionary<int, Win>();
    private Point downPoint_Drag = new Point(-1, -1);
    private int id_Drag = -1;
    private bool flag_Drag = false;

    public class Win
    {
        public Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        public Point downpoint = new Point();

        public Win()
        {
            canvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        }
    }

    private void Desktop_Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Point movePoint = e.GetPosition(Desktop_Canvas);

                    if (flag_Drag && downPoint_Drag != new Point(-1, -1))
                    {
                        double dy1 = movePoint.Y - downPoint_Drag.Y, x = -1, dx1 = movePoint.X - downPoint_Drag.X, y = -1;
                        downPoint_Drag = movePoint;
                        if (x == -1)
                            x = Canvas.GetLeft(dic[id_Drag].canvas) + dx1;
                        if (y == -1)
                            y = Canvas.GetTop(dic[id_Drag].canvas) + dy1;
                        Canvas.SetLeft(dic[id_Drag].canvas, x);
                        Canvas.SetTop(dic[id_Drag].canvas, y);
                    }
        }
        catch
        {
            MouseEventArgs ee = new MouseEventArgs((MouseDevice)e.Device, 10);
            Desktop_Canvas_MouseLeave(null, ee);
        }
    }

    private void Desktop_Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
  downPoint_Drag  = new Point(-1, -1);
            id_Drag =-1;
            flag_Drag = false;
        }
        catch
        {
            MouseEventArgs ee = new MouseEventArgs((MouseDevice)e.Device, 10);
            Desktop_Canvas_MouseLeave(null, ee);
        }
    }

    private void Desktop_Canvas_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseButtonEventArgs ee = new MouseButtonEventArgs((MouseDevice)e.Device, 10, MouseButton.Left);
            Desktop_Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(null, ee);
    }

    void canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {            
        downPoint_Drag = e.GetPosition(Desktop_Canvas);
        int hoverId = HoverWin(downPoint_Drag);
        flag_Drag = true;
        id_Drag = hoverId;
        dic[id_Drag].downpoint = new Point(downPoint_Drag.X, downPoint_Drag.Y);
    }

    private int HoverWin(Point p)
    {
        foreach (int i in dic.Keys)
        {
                if (dic[i].canvas.IsMouseOver)
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```